# ActiveAndroid: How to have different activeandroid meta-data in an android lib as well as android app

Tags: android, android-manifest, activeandroid

So, I have a Android library which is supposed to be used by multiple apps. The issue is the library uses Active android to store data and the manifest already has AA_DB_NAME, AA_DB_VERSION, AA_MODELS etc. defined.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
        android:value="lib.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
        android:value="20"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_SQL_PARSER"
        android:value="delimited" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_MODELS"
        android:value="com.mylib.models.UserModel,com.mylib.models.HomeModel"
```

The issue arises when the app which is supposed to use the lib is also using ActiveAndroid to store data and has the similar meta-data tag defined, as this causes manifest merging problems. Is there a way out? What should be the merging strategy in this case? Problem is I cannot change the library much at this stage as there are 4-5 apps already using it but I can suggest the apps to use merging strategy.